# Best way to typeset $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am interested to know what are some good ways to typeset $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$?

Basically it is 3 copies of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$.

I was thinking $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^3 \mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$$.

Will that be clear, or do we have to put extra brackets $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^3 (\mathbb{R}[x]/(x))$$ to avoid confusion?

Thanks.

Comment: How about$(\Bbb{R}[x]/(x))^3$? Or just $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Comment: How about $\langle x \rangle$ instead of $(x)$?

Comment: What is the difference between $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x \rangle$ and $\Bbb R$?